# Python Regular Expression newline is matched

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a string that has alphanumerics and some special characters but not the newline. But, whenever my string has a newline, it matches the newline character as well. I checked document for some flags but none of them looked relevant.

The following is a sample code in Python 3.6.2 REPL

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "do_not_match\n"
>>> p = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z\+\-\/\*\%\_\>\<=]*$")
>>> p.match(s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='do_not_match'>
```

The expected result is that it shouldn't match as I have newline at the end.

https://regex101.com/r/qyRw5s/1

I am a bit confused on what I am missing here.

Comment: Replace `$` with `\Z`

Comment: And it does not matter what version of Python it is.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. The context might be relevant but it is not a clear duplicate from the question perspective. So, this is why, I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. Also, I was trying to give as much as information as possible. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$` matches at the end of the string **before the newline** (if any).

If you don't want to match the newline at the end, use `\Z` instead of `$` in your regex.

See the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) module's documentation:

> '$'
>       Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string,
>
> \Z
>       Matches only at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation and it wasn't clear to me. I accept your answer. I am still not sure why regex101 was ignoring this fact though.

Comment: I guess, you need to use the actual enter key there instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: so true! thanks for showing me the obvious. :|